# What do you call a pair of function that are complements of each other?

Tags: terminology

I am looking for the right word to describe a function and its complement.

Here I am looking for the proper word to describe a couple of functions when applied in sequence the system reverts to its original state.

- Marshalling and Unmarshalling would be a subset of this
- Add and Remove

Idempotence comes to mind though I am not sure if it can apply to more than one operation.  Reversible could also do, but it seems a tad bit too general. Is there a right word that would describe this "systemic idempotence".

Comment: Maybe `inverse`?

Comment: You guys should post them as answers rather than comments, don`t be shy .^_^` nobody will bite you for it.

Comment: Group or pair? Because if you're discussing a group (N>=2), then it sounds like a group in the mathematical sense. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)

Comment: Good point ! though the argumentation is probably still valid for groups I guess in our case (computer science) they can always be reduced to pairs.  I will change the question to make it clearer.

Comment: A bad design? Stuff like Direct3D's BeginScene and EndScene are terribad..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Inverse function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) is the mathematical term.

[As much of Computer Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_computer_science) is based upon the discipline of Mathematics, I suggest you use that.

Answer (score 4):

- [Inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function)
- Mirror
- Reverse
- Converse
- Opposite
- Transpose
- Complement
- Antithesis
- [Dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: For argument's sake : Mirror implies a single operation that returns an inverted image of the original.  Opposite and Antithesis denotes states but leaves empty the dynamics of going from one to another.  Transpositions are not necessarily reversible so the word I am looking for would denote a subset of possible transpositions.  Complement, some operations referred to as complement would fit the description above but the word is also used to denote mutually exclusive solutions.  In this case I guess it would be too restrictive...

Comment: Which leaves Inverse (mentioned later in other answers), Reverse and Converse.

Comment: Dual sounds related to [coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine)

Answer (score 3):

Friend of mine proposed reciprocal (reciprocity)

Comment: Tell him to sign up and post his/her answers :) Reciprocal could work, it has [similar math roots](http://www.saskschools.ca/curr_content/mathb30/poly_rat/les11/notes.html) as inverse, but I prefer inverse, the meaning is more obvious.

Comment: I did but I think it is getting late for him (opposite side of our blue marble, at least this is the excuse I make up for him ;-P).

Answer (score 2):

I would use inverse or isomorphism. In that order.

Comment: Isomorphism, indeed !  thanks.  though i'm not certain for congruence.  Congruence, from what I understand states that an operation yeilds the same result for different parameters the paremeters are deemed congruent through that does not necessarily mean that we can invert the operation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_relation

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. Deleting

Comment: an isomorphism is a homomorphism with an inverse. how would you demonstrate the homomorphic structure of an `add(T value)` method? do you mean like a group homomorphism? if so, what would the binary operation of the codomain group be? and how is it at all relevant to the "complementness" of the function pair? and how would you argue that `remove(T value)` is the mathematical inverse of add?